# Django ContentFile get_available_name() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try to save an image object to an ImageField I get the following error:

> get_available_name() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'

The code looks like this:

```
imagen_url = form.cleaned_data['imagen_url']
respuesta = requests.get(imagen_url)
imagen = Image.open(StringIO(respuesta.content))
stringio_obj = StringIO()
imagen.save(stringio_obj, format="JPEG")
final_image = stringio_obj.getvalue()
carta.creador = request.user
carta.ultima_revision = datetime.today()
carta.save()
print("carta_id: %s" % carta.id)  # Works correctly till here

archivo_imagen = ContentFile(final_image, "0_" + carta.nombre)  # Guarda la original con un 0 adelante
carta.imagen_base.save("0_" + carta.nombre, archivo_imagen, save=True)
```

When I try ty to save the `ContentFile` object to the model`s ImageField, it doesn't work. It used to work in a lower version of Django, but since I shifted to django 1.10, it stopped working.

The model is simple, it looks like this:

```
def ubicar_img_base(instance, filename):
    nombre_archivo = "0_" + slugify(instance.nombre) + ".jpeg"
    path = "/".join([instance.grupo.nombre, nombre_archivo])
    return path

class CartaMagicPy(models.Model):
    imagen_base = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=ubicar_img_base)
```

Any advice will help

Answer (score 4):

Ok, hope this is useful to someone sometime: I solved it updating `boto` and `storages`. This would sound familiar to you if you use amazon AWS.